# How to install calendar_date_picker in rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, calendar

I've been trying to make this calendar_date_picker to work for more 
than two days, but without success.

I've tried installing it as a gem:

1. gem install calendar_date_select
2. include it in the gemfile, then run bundle install
3. Since rake calendar:install does NOT work... I manually placed each 
   file that I downloaded from the github into the asset repository 
   (rails 3.2) OR public folder (rails 3.0.5).
4. I have placed this line in the environment.rb file: 
   config.gem "calendar_date_select", :lib =>"calendar_date_select"
5. I have included the following in the application header: 
   <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> 
   <%= calendar_date_select_includes "blue" %>
6. I tried testing it in my views, but I always end up with this:

> undefined method `calendar_date_select_tag' for #<#: 
>   0x3ec49a8>
>
> 21:     <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_order_path(order) %>   22:
>   <%= link_to 'Destroy', order, :confirm => 'Are you  sure?',
>   :method => :delete %>
>
> 23:
>
> 24:   <%= calendar_date_select_tag "e_date" %>
>
> 25: <% end %>
>
> 26:

1. I've hacked into the lib/calendar_date_select.rb and changed / 
   public into /app/assets for rails 3.2. 
   For some reason, it doesn't recognize the calendar_date_select method.

Could someone please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It better to use jquery instead of using thirdparty calender on 3.2 . Here is one of the links

[Jquery Datepicker demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Please check [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars?view=comments) link too.

Comment: Works like a charm.
Some guy in Phrug said that calendar_date_select is already deprecated in Rails 3.2. Jquery_date_picker is a better choice.